# CSS background and form positioning zoom

Tags: php, html, css, forms

Good morning.

I am very new to CSS and been reading up on a few topics but completely stumped when I am trying to keep a form submit button over a BG image. As soon as I zoom on the page, the buttons move out of position.

Here is my CSS code for the BG:

```
body
{ 
background-image:url('../pics/BGs/FrontBG.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-attachment:fixed;
background-position:center;
background size: auto;
}
.bannerlogin1
{
position: relative;
top: 50;
left: 50;
}

.bannerlogin2
{
position: absolute;
top: 5px;
left: 400px;
}  

.bannerlogin3
{
position: absolute;
top: 5px;
left: 800px;
}

.bannerlogin4
{
position: absolute;
top: 5px;
left: 1250px;
}
```

And the code from my welcome page:

```
<BODY class="body" bgcolor="black">

<form action="../Nightlife.php">
<input class="bannerlogin1" type="submit" value="" style="width: 250px; height: 100px;    background-color:transparent; border:;" >
</form>

<form action="../Portrait.php">
<input class="bannerlogin2" type="submit" value="" style="width: 250px; height: 100px; background-color:transparent; border:;" >
</form>


<form action="../Contact.php">
<input class="bannerlogin3" type="submit" value="" style="width: 250px; height: 100px; background-color:transparent; border:;" >
</form>


<form action="../Client.php">
<input class="bannerlogin4" type="submit" value="" style="width: 250px; height: 100px; background-color:transparent; border:;" >
</form>
```

Thank you for any help :). I have a feeling I may be doing something fundamentally daft but have read a few things from w3 schools and the like and can not seem to find a concise answer to solve this.

Comment: Why are you using invisible inputs and forms to send users to pages? What's wrong with using absolutely-positioned `<a>` elements? Don't break the back-button!

Comment: Sorry, how do you mean? (I am very much self taught :(). You mean make an image for each button as an <a href> link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `form` needs to have a relative positioning. Otherwise when you zoom in, the input's will be positioned to the body of the page:

```
form{position:relative;}
```

Also, you should move your inline CSS of your submit buttons to your styles block:

```
input["submit"]{width: 250px; height: 100px; background-color:transparent;}
```

NOTE: ["submit"] is a CSS3 only attribute.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
I am going to try and use some jpgs instead of forms and use <a href> with relative positioning in the style sheet :). Wish me luck ha!